# adding numbers from html input with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to add the numbers I enter in an input form so I have to include it in an array and when I click  the button it adds the numbers in new line.

This is the html code of the input and button

```html
<input type="button" id="add" name="add" value="Add to sales order" />
```

```html
 <input type="text" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Enter Price"/>
```

Comment: So what have you tried.?

Comment: Be clearer, where are these "numbers" stored? Which array? Are you talking about PHP or JS?

Comment: i have an input form for price i want when i click the button price will add to the last price etc with php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this JSBin: http://jsbin.com/pahirikuwako/1/edit

So, the behavior here is next: as soon as you enter price and press "Add sales to order" the new line will appear with specified price.
If you was thinking of any other behvaior please try to explain it more clear and I will update JSBin respectively or you can try to do it yourself.